# DRY scope methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, scope, dry

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.7 and I would like to DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) my scope methods.

In the model file I have:

```
class Articles::Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :article_related_to, lambda { |user| where('articles_categories_article_relationships.user_id = ?', user.id) }
  scope :comment_related_to, lambda { |user| where('comments_articles_article_category_relationships.user_id = ?', user.id) }


  has_many :comment_article_category_relationships
  has_many :comments,
    :class_name  => 'Comments::Articles::ArticleCategoryRelationship',
    :through     => :comment_article_category_relationships,
    :source      => :comment

  has_many :article_relationships
    :class_name  => 'Articles::Categories::ArticleRelationship',
  has_many :articles,
    :through     => :article_relationships,
    :source      => :article
end
```

By using the above code I can do this:

```
@comment.article_categories.comment_related_to(@current_user)
@comment.article_categories.article_related_to(@current_user)
```

*How can I "DRY" scopes methods in order to make possible for both `:article_related_to` and `:comment_related_to` to use something like the following*

```
@comment.article_categories.related_to(@current_user)

# In order to pass the correct "context" 'article' or 'comment' I thought 
# something like
#
# @comment.article_categories.related_to(@current_user, 'article')
# @comment.article_categories.related_to(@current_user, 'comment')
#
# but, maybe, there is a way to retrieve automatically that "context" so to
# write only one "DRYed" scope method.
```

**?**

Comment: Whew, my eyes are bleeding just trying to keep this thing straight! Is there anyway you could just get what you're looking for via the @current_user object?

Comment: @dogenpunk - BTW: "My eyes are bleeding just trying to keep this thing straight!"... what do you mean? - In my case I can get what I am looking for via the '@current_user' object but, on this other side, I will have the same issue as described in the question.

Comment: I think this is a DRY too far personally: readability beats DRY for me and this is making the code much harder to read.  DRY should be about keeping functionality or values etc in a single place rather than minimising lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I can offer is the following:

```
scope :related_to, lambda { |user, context|
  tbl = context == :article ? :articles_categories_article_relationships
                            : :comments_articles_article_category_relationships
  where("#{tbl}.user_id = ?", user.id)
}
```

That gives you the `@comment.article_categories.related_to(@current_user, :article)` like you suggested.  But I'm in agreement with Max Williams.  This obfuscates your code unnecessarily with no real gain.

If you are really eager to obfuscate your code further you can do this:

```
def self.method_missing(method, *args)
  if method =~ /^(.*)_related_to$/
    related_to(*args, $1)
  else
    super
  end
end

def self.related_to(user, context)
  through = reflections[context.to_s.pluralize.to_sym].options[:through]
  tbl = reflections[through].options[:class_name].underscore.pluralize.gsub('/', '_')
  where("#{tbl}.user_id = ?", user.id)
end
```

Please note that I believe your associations have a couple of typos.  Probably should be:

```
has_many :comment_article_category_relationships,
  :class_name  => 'Comments::Articles::ArticleCategoryRelationship'
has_many :comments,
  :through     => :comment_article_category_relationships,
  :source      => :comment

has_many :article_relationships,
  :class_name  => 'Articles::Categories::ArticleRelationship'
has_many :articles,
  :through     => :article_relationships,
  :source      => :article
```